# Convert Text within Tables to Plain text with linebreaks

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Given a chunk of HTML that displays data nicely in `<div>` and `<table>`, how can all the HTML/CSS markup be removed while maintaining the text originally found in individual cells and divs now separated with only line breaks?

Current attempt shown here will output one long continuous paragraph instead of maintaining the separation when its in the div or table form.

**Original HTML:** http://pastebin.com/63N3Kg16

**Output:**

```
John Smith | SomeName Realty | (xxx) 939-4835 Allston St, Cambridge, MA Very spacious under renovation with SST/Granite, porch, minutes to MIT, redline, Nov/1 4BR/1BA Apartment $3,400/month Bedrooms 4 Bathrooms 1 full, 0 partial Sq Footage Unspecified Parking None Pet Policy No pets Deposit $0 DESCRIPTION Triple decker building secondfloor apt aprox 2000 sqf with large bedrooms, kitchen, pantry, porch, d/w, all woodfloor and ZTilded in the kitchen, new bath. utilities extra,Nov/1 see additional photos below Contact info: Payman Ahmadifar Bayside Realty (xxx) 939-4835 Posted: Sep 24, 2012, 6:55am PDT
```

**PHP**

```
nl2br(trim(strip_tags($html)));
```

---

**Expected Output**

Plain text with either `<br>` or newline, no `<div>` or `<table>` HTML markup. Basically to make the text more readable, maintaining the spacing/separation structure of the original, but with no CSS stylings or HTML markup except for `<br>`.

```
John Smith | SomeName Realty | (xxx) 939-4835 

Allston St, Cambridge, MA 

Very spacious under renovation with SST/Granite, porch, minutes to MIT, redline, Nov/1 

4BR/1BA Apartment $3,400/month 

Bedrooms 4 
Bathrooms 1 full, 0 partial 
Sq Footage Unspecified 
Parking None 
Pet Policy No pets 
Deposit $0 

DESCRIPTION 
Triple decker building secondfloor apt aprox 2000 sqf with large bedrooms, kitchen, pantry, porch, d/w, all woodfloor and ZTilded in the kitchen, new bath. utilities extra,Nov/1 see additional photos below 

Contact info: Payman Ahmadifar Bayside Realty (xxx) 939-4835 
Posted: Sep 24, 2012, 6:55am PDT
```

Comment: Have you tried strip_tags($html, '<table><tr><td><br><p><div>')

Comment: can you add the expected output please

Comment: Also nl2br is not surely to have desired effect as html might not contain any nl's

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I do not wish to have any stylings like `<table> <p> <div>` in the final output. Only new lines, `<br>` and `<strong>` if possible.

Comment: Where does the John Smith come from? And where do the | come from? And you want to view that in the browser? or save it to some file?

Comment: Well I thought you wanted to retain divs anx tables as you say so in the first sentence. But just use strip_tags($html,'<br><strong>') then

Comment: If the original html contains only table markup and no `<br>` and `<strong>`, wont I get the same output where everything is in one continuous line? *Edited my original post to be clearer, thanks!*

Comment: @Gordon I replaced the actual name with John Smith. `|` comes from the original html

Comment: There is neither | nor John Smith in the HTML you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play around with some string manipulations

Try

```
$string = strip_tags($html);
$string = str_replace(chr(32).chr(32).chr(32),"*****",$string);
$newString = array_map(function($var){ return  trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ',$var)); },explode("*****",$string));
print(implode("\n", $newString));
```

[See Live Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZWMxMd)

Comment: Output looks beautiful! Maybe need 1 more function to replace multiple `\n` with a single `\n`. Is `*****` just a temporary placeholder/separator?

Comment: @Nyxynyx am sure you have a better understanding of what you want .. was just playing around